# Why are tasks without parent backlog not displayed in the sprint - backlog

Tags: tfs, scrum, backlog

If I add a task and don't associate a parent backlog item or bug, the task does not show in my sprint backlog. However, if I create a query from my sprint backlog, I can see the task.

Why don't tasks added to the current sprint appear in the sprint backlog if they do not have a parent backlog item/bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think the fundamental reason is because product backlog items are added to a sprint and tasks are not. When you look at your sprint backlog, you are looking at product backlog items that have been taken into that sprint.

Comment: I can set the iteration of a task to Sprint 1, even without a backlog item as parent. Why does TFS allow it if tasks are not added to a sprint ?

Comment: I don't know why TFS does that. But if I relate it back to how I would use a physical scrum board, I know that having an orphaned task makes no sense. The sprint backlog items are the work that the scrum team have accepted for the sprint. Tasks are simply a deconstruction of those items to create a plan for how the work will be done. If we find a new task, I'd want to either attach it to a sprint backlog item or make a new product backlog item and put it on the product backlog. Therefore, I'd say that TFS is modelling the physical board appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

When had a similar problem, it depended on the query behind the sprint backlog (by query not via the board).
There it was all task of a backlog item fir that sprint displayed. That means if
the backlog item was not for that sprint the task was not displayed and of course without a backlog item it was also not displayed. We changed the query to show all task related to that sprint and all their parents.
But that is an assumption. Please provide more information.

Comment: This should be a comment, as it's not a verified solution to the problem.

Comment: Thx for the advice, I will correct this ASAP (As far as i can comment others posts).